# How to remove the "autocomlete" option from the top of the suggestions list?

Tags: fig

Using Fig on my work macbook, and I'm trying to figure out how to disable one specific feature of the application.  90% of the time when I hit Tab, fig just copies the selected command into the terminal. Then I hit Enter to execute the command.

The problem is, in some specific situations Fig inserts an "execute command" at the top of the list.
[image: example]

Note the red `>` symbol, meaning that hitting tab here will RUN that command.  I foolishly ran a query similar to the above image the other day, and without thinking I typed `rm -rf <my file>` and hit tab to see it in the terminal to check it over.  But this option was present in the suggestions, so hitting Tab executed the command instead, and my file was gone forever.

Totally my fault, I wasn't being careful.  BUT, I'd like to remove this option from my suggestions list for my own safety in the future.  Is there a way to turn this off?  I've scoured the settings and looked around online, but I can't find anything.